# Two responsive DIVs, left maxes out at max-width, right takes the rest?

Tags: html, css

Have a question that's similar to a lot of others asked on here, but with a bit more complexity than I could find. I have two DIV columns, and I would like them to both be responsive to the container they are in (which uses bootstrap to change the container width based on the browser size).

The **left div** needs to be responsive up to a *max-width of 597px wide*. It contains an image which is using a width:100% so it shrinks as the left column shrinks, but 597px wide is the max size of the image.

The **right div** needs to be able to do two things... fully use the rest of the space not used by the left div in the container if there's room... BUT, if the window is sized smaller and the right div has less than 250px of the container space left when next to the left div I need it to go ahead and move the itself underneath the left div and make it 100% width.

**EDIT -** Another thing i just thought of... to keep the left div from making the image too small, when the left image is BELOW the max-width of 597px, I need the aspect ratio between the two divs to be 60% on the left, the 40% on the right.

I figure using @media (min-width:xx){ commands would be a big help here... it looks like Bootstrap is changing the container size at min-width:506px, min-width: 768px, and min-width: 992px.

I originally tried percentages, but that didn't end up working well and the right div wasn't taking the rest of the room when the left div hit the max-width size.

```
@media (min-width: 506px){
    .WPProductCLeft {     
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px; }
    .WPProductCRight { 
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px; }
    }
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .WPProductCLeft { width: 66.66666667%; max-width: 597px; }
    .WPProductCRight { width: 33.3%;; }
    }
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .WPProductCLeft { width: 597px; }
    .WPProductCRight { width: 39%; }
    }
```

Obviously the left div has theclass of **.WPProductCLeft** and the right has **.WPProductCRight**. Help?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Well, after fiddling with the code a lot more, I seemed to figure it out.

```
@media (min-width: 506px){
    .WPProductCLeft { 
        margin:auto;  
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
    .WPProductCRight { 
        margin:auto;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .WPProductCLeft {
        width: 60%;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px; 
    }
    .WPProductCRight {
        width: auto;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
    .WPProductCLeft {
        width: 597px;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px; 
    }
    .WPProductCRight {
        width: auto; 
    }
}
```

The trick was using width:auto, that made a big difference. Didn't even realize you could have an auto width in css. Since the container width is predefined in size by the bootstrap based on browser width, controlling the left div was the biggest key while letting the right div just fill in the rest with auto. Using the media min-height, I was able to manipulate the two divs to responsive resize themselves based on the container divs size in that range. Not the prettiest code ever, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

For well using of media query in this case we have to know which are the break points, so lets do a simple math to find them.

First lets find this:

> if the window is sized smaller and the right div has less than 250px
>   of the container space left when next to the left div I need it to go
>   ahead and move the itself underneath the left div and make it 100%
>   width.

At this point the **right div** has `width: 40%` so all that we have to do is found what is the total width when **right div** has a width of 250px, we can use cross product: 250 * 100 / 40 = **625**, now we have the first break point.

Lets found the second:

> The left div needs to be responsive up to a max-width of 597px wide

Pretty the same **left div** has `width: 60%` now we want the total width when it has 597px so would be 597 * 100 / 60 = **995** and here is our second break point.

Now lets use them:

```css
.WPProductCLeft,
.WPProductCRight{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}
.WPProductCLeft{
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 597px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
.WPProductCRight{
    width: calc(100% - 597px); /*to use the rest of the space not used by the left div*/
    background: #BEECCD;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


@media (max-width: 995px){
    .WPProductCRight{
        width: 40%;  /*to set aspect ratio between the two divs to be 60% on the left, the 40% on the right.*/
    }
}
@media (max-width: 625px){
    .WPProductCLeft,
    .WPProductCRight{
        width: 100%;  /*left div to go ahead and move the right div underneath the left div and make it 100% width.*/
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="WPProductCLeft"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt=""></div>
    <div class="WPProductCRight"></div>
</div>
```

The above snippet is just to illustrate I think in that way you could understand it better, now lets do it in the right way using mobile first:

Here a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/bezx9dwx/1/) to play with

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.WPProductCLeft,
.WPProductCRight{
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;  /*left div to go ahead and move the right div underneath the left div and make it 100% width.*/
}
.WPProductCLeft{
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
.WPProductCRight{    
    background: #BEECCD;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


@media (min-width: 626px){ /*to set aspect ratio between the two divs to be 60% on the left, the 40% on the right.*/
    .WPProductCLeft{
        max-width: 597px;
        width: 60%;
    }
    .WPProductCRight{
        width: 40%;  
    }
}
@media (min-width: 996px){
    .WPProductCRight{
        width: calc(100% - 597px); /*to use the rest of the space not used by the left div*/
        
    }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="WPProductCLeft"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt=""></div>
    <div class="WPProductCRight"></div>
</div>
```